# Проектирование базы данных

Tags: база-данных, er-diagram

Есть некое отношение которое содержит след. атрибуты `id, name, dic1_id, dic2_id, dic3_id` и т.д. В полях `dic#_id` содержатся внешние ключи таблиц справочников содержащие поля `id` и `name`. Вопрос следующий как отобразить эту зависимость в ER-диаграмме? у кого нет под рукой программы по построению диаграмм прошу воспользоватьс [draw.io](https://www.draw.io/)

Answer (score 1):

Если количество dic#_id не ограничено, то лучше отказаться от физических констрэйнтов. Ввести 2 дополнительных таблицы. Одна - справочник атрибутов, вторая - хранилище значений атрибутов. И уже на уровне приложения делать нужные джоины. Вот [примерная схема](http://goo.gl/qoy8B). В поле attrValue таблицы MainEntityAttrs хранятся как раз нужные Вам идентификаторы из справочных таблиц

[image: примерная схема]